# convert date and time into selected timezone

Tags: java, jsp, datetime

i have a list of time zones of diffrent countries in a selectbox and have a  textbox where user can enter date and time in a specified format only which is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.

i want entered timezone to be converted in to selcted timezone from list.
How can i do this.

```
<option value="Pacific/Apia">( GMT -11:0 ) West Samoa Time ( Pacific/Apia )</option>
<option value="Pacific/Midway">( GMT -11:0 ) Samoa Standard Time ( Pacific/Midway )</option>
<option value="Pacific/Niue">( GMT -11:0 ) Niue Time ( Pacific/Niue )</option>
<option value="Pacific/Pago_Pago">( GMT -11:0 ) Samoa Standard Time ( Pacific/Pago_Pago )</option>
<option value="Pacific/Samoa">( GMT -11:0 ) Samoa Standard Time ( Pacific/Samoa )</option>
<option value="US/Samoa">( GMT -11:0 ) Samoa Standard Time ( US/Samoa )</option>
```

**Textbox**

```
<input type="text" name="createdOnGMTDate" id="createdOnGMTDate"  style="width:200px;"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to format date with a certain pattern with a predefined locale. For example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-11"));
String now = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, may be this will help you.

```
DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Athens"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(instance2.getTime()))
```